# Button with icon in Apple Watch notification

Tags: ios, button, notifications, apple-watch

I have in my UI a button with icon in the notification.I have got the buttons through code

```
 var approveAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()      
 approveAction.identifier = "approveButtonAction"      

 approveAction.title = "Approve"     

 approveAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground    

 approveAction.destructive = false         

 approveAction.authenticationRequired = false
```

but how to get the icon also preceding the text?
Please provide some inputs.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  What do you mean "preceding the text"?

Comment: In my button i should have an icon at the left side and then the title Approve.

Comment: Can anyone help on this?